# How to customize PagerTitleStrip android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, pagertitlestrip

I must customize a PagerTitleStrip in ViewPager in this way:
[image]

I have to create circles with numbers corresponding to the inside pages, the circle in the middle has to be bigger. Anyone have any suggestions?