# Custom title for android fragment using viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe, custom-titlebar

I want to add custom title for each fragment, which is in `viewPager`. How can I implement. In the below code, I need to add custom title for `FragmentMain`, `FragmentMore` and `FragmentChatView`.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // page adapter between fragment list and view pager
    public static PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    // view pager
    public ViewPager mPager;
    // activity data
    public String p2text, p3text;
    public static List<Fragment> fragments;// = buildFragments();
    // / ArrayList<String> categories = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};
    ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    static final String LOG_TAG = "HomeActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragments = new ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();
        categories.add("1");
        categories.add("2");
        categories.add("3");
        categories.add("4");
        categories.add("5");
        categories.add("6");
        categories.add("7");

        addFragments(FragmentMore.class.getName(), 1);
        addFragments(FragmentMain.class.getName(), 2);
        addFragments(FragmentChatView.class.getName(), 3);

        mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, categories);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }

    public void addFragments(String className, int position) {
        // List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragments = new
        // ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();

        // (int i = 0; i<categories.size(); i++) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("position", position);
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, className, b));
        // }

        // return fragments;
    }

    public void removeFragments(String className, int position) {
        // List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragments = new
        // ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();

        // (int i = 0; i<categories.size(); i++) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("position", position);
        fragments.remove(Fragment.instantiate(this, className, b));
        // }

        // return fragments;
    }

    private List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> buildFragments() {
        List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>();

        for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("position", i);
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentSearch.class.getName(), b));
        }

        return fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onPause");
    }
}

public class FragmentMore extends Fragment  {
    Button btnWrite;
    public String ptext="More";
    static final String LOG_TAG = "Fragment More";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    // onCreateView : 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // inflate view from layout
        View view = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.more,container,false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onPause");
    }
}
```

//More layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/screen_back_color"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/more_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/more_button_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/more_button_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_grey"
        android:text="@string/settings"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/more_button_font_size"
        android:textColor="@color/white" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTermsAndConditions"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/more_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/more_button_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/more_button_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_grey"
        android:text="@string/termsandCondition"
        android:textAllCaps="true"

        android:textColor="@color/white" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

//Custom title layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/main_edittext_fontsize"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:text="title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your more layout..

Comment: I have posted more layout and custom title layout. I want to add custom title in my fragmentMore.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for PagerTitleStrip element.

Check out this section of android tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip

Comment: I need a Custom title have textview with imageview. Is it possible in PagerTitleStrip.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720221/how-to-customize-pagertitlestrip-android